# Can a trained recognition model be used to generate a sample?

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification

Suppose we have trained a cat classification network. It takes in an image (as a vector) x and returns $\hat{y}\in(0,1)$. The loss function is the typical cross entropy function. Shouldn't it be possible to now perform gradient descent on the space of images to obtain an example of a "cat picture" that our network really thinks is a cat?

I expect that this process would give us something very ugly, and not actually cat-like, but I am just curious if this works.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for "Autoencoders". Check this out-https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Generative models](https://openai.com/blog/generative-models/) can. Among others, you can use GAN, auto-encoders or VAE, ... As far as I know, discriminative approaches can not generate a sample.

Hope it helps.